# Remove event before when run child event

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, dom-events

In this example, when I click button so has two alert, how remove event divExamp when click button and just has one alert.

```
<button id="abc">sdfsdfsdf</button>
<div id="example">zczczxczxc</div>

<script>
let divExamp = document.querySelector('#example');
document.querySelector('#abc').addEventListener('click', async e =>{
    divExamp.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<button id="click">click</button>');   
    document.querySelector('#click').addEventListener('click', async e =>{
        alert('click!');
    })
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let divExamp = document.querySelector('#example');
let abc = document.querySelector('#abc');

abc.addEventListener('click', temp);

function temp(e) {
  abc.removeEventListener('click', temp);
  divExamp.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<button id="click">click</button>');
  document.querySelector('#click').addEventListener('click', e => {
    alert('click!');
  });
}
```

```html
<button id="abc">sdfsdfsdf</button>
<div id="example">zczczxczxc</div>
```